# How I can save my data when location changed in AngularJs app?

Tags: angularjs, devextreme

I have a simple *AngularJs* application, at the *HomePage.html* I have a *dx-datagrid* with all data, to *onSelectionChanged* method I added the next code:

```
onSelectionChanged: function (e) {
        $scope.itemIdFromShowButton = e.selectedRowsData[0].id;
        $scope.cardSelectedArray = e.selectedRowsData[0];
        $scope.allRecordsOfCard= businessLogicOfMyApp.getVardsRecordsByCardId($scope.itemIdFromShowButton, $scope.recordsArray);
        $scope.localArray = $scope.chaptersArray.concat($scope.jdskla);
        console.log($scope.localArray);
    },
```

here i get all Records of card, and concat it with secondary array, it works:
[image]

but, after my location is changet - array is empty:
[image]

I want use is array like a *dataSource* in my *dx-treeview* at my *CardDetail.html* page.

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/HomePartial.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/createnewcard', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/CreateNewCard.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/carddetail/:cardId', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/CardDetails.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
.when('/createnewrecord/:cardId', {
    templateUrl: "Partials/CreateNewRecordToCard.html",
    controller: "defaultController"
})
  ;

$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);
```

may be somebody know how i can save my data ? Thanks for your answers !

P.S. i initialized  `$scope.localArray = [];` at header of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `$localStorage` to save your array when is getting populated and if the state changes check for value in the local storage. If there is value in the local storage use that value for the array value

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your controller is being instantiated for each template. Instead of writing `controller: "defaultController"` inside your route provider, create a div in html page where you will load your your view and write `ng-controller="defaultController"` in that div. example:

```
<div ng-contoller="defaultController"> 
<!-- other part of your code -->
<div ng-view> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I hope it will not work. DOM change will happen here and it will again re initialise the controller

Comment: DOM changes will happen in ng-view div only

Comment: I made it when I created my app) trouble was what I have two objects of my controller, for check it I wrote console.log("Bibb"); at the top of my jsController, and I have two messages in console after start. I rewrote my code, and get id from url, and get records by id from my factory. Thnx for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use localstorage or angular services/factory to store your array and get it when state changes by injecting that service/factory in your controller.